# django ,model migrate: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: django, django-models

I am writing a apps and run `makemigrations` and `migrate` multiple time when i add new field.

And now i have added a new `foreignKey` Field in models and then i run the command:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

after this, i run this command `python3 manage.py migrate` but it throws me following error

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

and later again i run this command `pythion3 manage.py migrate --fake` and i have successfully migrated and got another problem, when i go to django admin templates and click on my models to add data, it throws me this error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/booking/seats/
no such column: booking_seats.seat_for_id
```

I am not getting whats wrong with it, can anyone help me to fix this?

for your reference, see my models:

```
class Seats(models.Model):
    alias = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    seat_no = models.IntegerField(
        choices=SeatChoices.choices(),
    )
    availability = models.IntegerField(
        choices=SeatAvailability.choices(),
        default=SeatAvailability.AVAILABLE
    )
    seat_for = models.ForeignKey('booking.show', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.seat_no)

class Show(models.Model):
    alias = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    show_schedule = models.IntegerField(
        choices=ShowSchedule.choices(),
    )
    movie = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.show_schedule)
```

I just added this new field `seat_for = models.ForeignKey('booking.show', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` then i facing the problem

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: You only added a `ForeignKey` or did you make other modifications before migrating?

Comment: Before migrate, i have added some data using django admi tempaltes

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your model is not with a capital, as Python is case sensitive. It should be like this:

```
seat_for = models.ForeignKey('booking.Show', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```